# My app getting Crash

Tags: objective-c, camera, uiimage, uicollectionview

I am creating app like , which will take photos and shows the taken photos in thumbnail as scrolling part below the camera view .it is taking photos.but if i take more than 30 pictures my app is getting crash .So i connect my iPod with Xcode and i run ,[image: Getting error like this]  .I don't why it happens .I think may be memory issue .because i am  taking more pictures.If it is memory issue please tell me what i should do for that .please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to Reduce the size of image

```
- (UIImage )imageWithImage:(UIImage )image convertToSize:(CGSize)size
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return destImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nithya , let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Classic memory issue; you are using memory quickly enough that your app and, likely, the debugging conduit are being killed by the system.

To fix?  Use less memory.  Or, 'ore specifically, release the full sized images as soon as you have thumbnails generated.